# What is the minimal polynomial of $A^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m_A = x^6 - 4x^4+3x^2 +1$. What is the minimal polynomial of $A^2$?

I'd be glad for an hint/direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an obvious cubic polynomial that $A^2$ satisfies.  (Don't worry that $A$ is a matrix.)  If $A^2$ satisfied a smaller polynomial than a cubic, then $A$ would satisfy a smaller polynomial than a degree 6.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand :/

Comment: if you take $f(x) = x^3 - 4x^2 + 3x + 1,$ then $f(A^2) = 0.$ now if $A^2$ satisfies a monic polynomial of degree $\leq 2,$ then $A$ will also satisfy a monic polynomial of $\leq 4$ (why?). and that will contradict that $m_A$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.